# Разложение подынтегральной функции с помощью формулы Эйлера

Tags: c#

[Решение интеграла в преобразовании Фурье](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501206/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5)

Численным методам этот интеграл не решить из за наличия комплексной мнимой единицы,порекомендовали [Формула Эйлера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) с разложением подынтегральной функции на косинус и синус

Вопрос возник с применением Формулы Эйлера

Получается нужно вручную разделить формулу на 2 части присвоить согласно формуле Эйлера каждую часть к интегралу.
Или существует другой вариант?

```
public void frmEiler(int U,int T)
        {
         double x1=0,x2=0;
           ///U*Math.Exp(-j * w * t) dt///формула
             double j = Math.Sqrt(-1);// мнимая единица
            double f = 0,w = 0;
            int t = 1;
            f = 1 / T;
            w = 2 * Math.PI * f;
            Math.Exp(-j * w * t) =U* Math.Cos(w * t) + j * Math.Sin(t);
  x1=Math.Cos(w * t);
  x2=j * Math.Sin(t);
        }

        public double func1(double x1)
        {
 ///1-ая часть подыинтегральной функции
            return;
        }

        public double func2(double x2)
        {
///2-ая часть подыинтегральной функции
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Math.Sqrt(-1) -> NaN. Скорее всего здесь нужны символьные вычисления. Странно, что на шарпе такие задачи дают, а не используют специальные программы для математики (matlab, mathcad и Wolfram Mathematica. Ну, либо использовать готовые библиотеки.

Comment: А Вы данный код уже компилировали? Math.Exp(-j * w * t) = Math.Cos(w * t) + j * Math.Sin(t); - уже здесь ошибка.

Comment: Да там ошибка я знаю,но это временное.

Сейчас мне хочется понять как разложить подынтегральную функцию с помощью Эйлера

Готовыми библиотеками нельзя пользоватся,так как диплом и антиплагиат.

на Маткаде и Матлабе диплом нельзя писать,использовать Си Шарп.

Comment: А быстрое преобразование тоже не подходит?

Comment: fft и alglib запрещено пользоваться.

Comment: А разве U - это не функция?

Comment: Данные можете указать? Вот U - это константа или функция чего-то? Нужны начальные условия. Я попробую Вам помочь. хотя в математике не силен, но для проверки нужны данные.

Comment: U и T это переменные(амплитуда и период,к примеру U=10,T=1) которые я ввожу c клавиатуры.
j это мнимая единица.

t = 1;--ось где будут располагается гармоники,я взял единицу как отправная точка тестирования.
f = 1 / T;
w = 2 * Pi * f;Частота

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего с помощью формулы Эйлера Вы решили избавиться от мнимой единицы, чтобы вычислить численно интегралы. Я в математике не силен, не знаю верно ли, но решил попробовать.

> Получается нужно вручную разделить формулу на 2 части присвоить
>   согласно формуле Эйлера каждую часть к интегралу

По формуле Эйлера нужно вычислить интеграл sin'а и интеграл cos'а. Дальше из полученных результатов получить комплексное число.

### Что я делал

Я создал класс `NumericalIntegration`, который интегрирует функцию с помощью [Численного интегрирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Т.к. существует несколько методов решения (я буду называть их способы, чтобы не путать с термином ***метод*** в программировании), поэтому я решил создать интерфейс, который будет подразумевать какой-то способ решения. А реализация этого интерфейса уже будет конкретным способом решения. Я так сделал, чтобы при разработки можно было добавить еще какие-то способы решения.

```
interface NumericalIntegrationRule
{
    double Calculate(Func<double, double> func, double min, double max, double subintervalsCount);
}
```

У способа решения должен быть метод, который принимает функцию `func`, отрезок интегрирования `[min,max]` и число подинтервалов `n`, т.е. насколько частей делим отрезок, чем больше отрезков, тем больше точность интегрирования. Конечно же, лучше было бы сделать *погрешность*, но я по-быстрому заложился на количество отрезков. Можете сами потом изменить это.

А в классе интегрирования `NumericalIntegration` уже будет вызов нужного способа решения. Нужный способ передается через конструктор. Плюс добавил параметры по умолчанию: число отрезков.

```
class NumericalIntegration
{
    public readonly NumericalIntegrationRule DefaultRule = null;
    public readonly int DefaultSubintervalsCount = 100000;

    public NumericalIntegration()
    {
        DefaultRule = new TrapezoidalRule();
    }

    public NumericalIntegration(NumericalIntegrationRule defaultRule)
    {
        DefaultRule = defaultRule;
    }

    public NumericalIntegration(NumericalIntegrationRule defaultRule, int defaultSubintervalsCount) : this(defaultRule)
    {
        DefaultSubintervalsCount = defaultSubintervalsCount;
    }

    public double Calculate(NumericalIntegrationRule rule, Func<double, double> func, double min, double max, double subintervalsCount)
    {
        return rule.Calculate(func, min, max, subintervalsCount);
    }

    public double Calculate(Func<double, double> func, double min, double max)
    {
        return Calculate(DefaultRule, func, min, max, DefaultSubintervalsCount);
    }
}
```

Я реализовал только метод трапеций:

```
class TrapezoidalRule : NumericalIntegrationRule
{
    public double Calculate(Func<double, double> func, double min, double max, double subintervalsCount)
    {
        double result = 0;
        double step = (max - min) / subintervalsCount;

        for (double i = min; i < max; i += step)
            result += ((func(i) + func(i + step)) / 2) * step;

        return result;
    }
}
```

А можно было бы на каждый способ решения в классе `NumericalIntegration` создать отдельный метод этого `CalculateWithTrapezoidalRule`, `CalculateWithRectangleRule` и т.д.

Теперь у нас есть классы для численного интегрирования. Можно их использовать для нахождения спектральной плотности. Я не в курсе как у Вас устроена система, поэтому я работал в консольном приложении и в этом приложении вынес расчет плотности в отдельный статический метод:

```
static Complex GetSpectralDensity(double amplitude, double frequency, double time)
{
    NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
    double real = amplitude * integration.Calculate(x => Math.Cos(-frequency * x), 0, time);
    double imaginary = amplitude * integration.Calculate(x => Math.Sin(-frequency * x), 0, time);
    return new Complex(real, imaginary);
}
```

Все как в формуле Эйлера: интегрируются обе части, а потом на основе их результатов создается комплексное число, которое и будет равно значения плотности.

Дальше, решил проверить результаты моей программы с результатами Mathcad.
[image: Скрин из Mathcad]
Mathcad, вроде бы, говорит, что результаты, вычисленные после преобразования по формуле Эйлера, будут такие же, как и результаты, полученные без преобразования.
Проверил на этих же данных и свою программу.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double amplitude = 25;
    double time = 50;

    for (int frequency = -100, counter = 0; frequency <= 100; frequency++, counter++)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", counter, GetSpectralDensity(amplitude, frequency, time).ToString());
}
```

[image: Скрин результата программы]

Вроде бы, похоже. Попробуйте реализовать другие способы решения и вычислить с помощью их.

Забыл сказать, что я использовал сборку **System.Numerics.dll** для представления комплексного числа. Надеюсь, ее то можно использовать :)