# Некорректное вычисление графика в ZedGraph

Tags: c#

Вопрос с преобразованием решился но вопрос с рисованием графика всё тот же.
Нужно нарисовать такой график

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С математической точки зрения,всё сделано по формулам
f-частота была найдена путём деления 1 на период Т(тау)
w-амега частота была найдена согласно формулам и выражена в аргументе.

Но это математически,но реализация в программе совсем другая.
на вход я подаю frc,frc1-это мои границы построения графика,к примеру от -3 до 3
И следовательно в цикле уже находить значение f и w.

```
 public static Complex GetSpectralDensity(double U, double frequency, double T,double x)
                    {
                 NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
for (double fx= frc, counter = 1; fx <= frc1; fx++, counter++)
{
                 double f = 1 / T;
                 double w = 2 * Math.PI * f;
                 }
return U * integration.Calculate(t => Math.Cos(w * t), 0, T) - Complex.ImaginaryOne * U * integration.Calculate(t => Math.Sin(w * t), 0, T);  
                    }
```

После происходит процедура взятия числа и его модуля.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Было перепробовано много различных вариантов(такие как взятие мнимого числа,изменения параметров по умолчанию) но приемлемый реализован ниже.

```
public static double GetSinModul(double U, double frequency, double T,int frc,int frc1)
        {
            double x2=0;
            List<Complex> value = new List<Complex>();
            value.Add(GetSpectralDensity(U, frequency, T, 1,frc,frc1));
            value.ForEach(x1=>x2=x1.Real);
             return U * T * Math.Abs(Math.Sin(x2) /x2);   
        }
```

Отрывок метода рисования моего графика.Впрочем это отрывок рисует то что ему даст метод.

```
for (double fr = xmin; fr <= xmax; fr += shag)
             {    
                 for (frequency = frc, counter = 1; frequency <= frc1; frequency++, counter++)
                 {
                     list.Add(fr,GetSinModul(U,frequency,T,frc,frc1));                   
                 }
             }

            LineItem curve = panel1.AddCurve("Line",list,Color.Blue,SymbolType.None);
```

Приблизительно график совсем чуть-чуть близок к тому что нужно но не хватает т.н. лепестков(полукругов между числами где спектральная плотность уходит в 0).

И оно так и выводит,но до оригинала далеко.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в не построении графика, а в неправильных расчетах. Идем по порядку.

Когда Вы [в прошлый раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502428) спрашивали про нахождение спектральной плотности через интеграл, я думал, что по заданию Вы можете использовать только эту исходную формулу, а работа заключается в демонстрации применения численных методов на практике. Но сейчас Вы приводите преобразованную формулу, и я понимаю, что цель задачи просто сделать расчеты этой плотности на шарпе, любыми способами. Поэтому работа сильно упрощается.

#### Идем с самого начала.

Вы приводили формулу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эту формулу можно упростить, посчитав интеграл, тем самым нам не придется высчитывать интеграл программно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только при реализации нужно будет учесть деление на 0. При омега = 0, спектральная плотность равна:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше вы приводите формулу, которая высчитывает спектральную плотность амплитуд. Эта формула **неверна** для сигнала заданного на промежутках **от 0 до *тау***. Вы верно сказали, что для нахождения спектральной плотности амплитуд нужно посчитать модуль спектральной плотности, но в в вашей формуле этот модуль высчитывается на основе преобразованной формулы спектральной плотности для сигнала на промежутках [-*тау*/2,*тау*/2]. Вам эта формула, во-первых, не подходит, а во-вторых, она Вам и не нужна. Когда Вы найдете спектральную плотность, вы возьмете модуль ее значения (модуль комплексного числа), тем самым получите спектральную плотность амплитуд.

#### Реализация

Получается, что не нужны классы для высчитывания определенных интегралов, которые я Вам [в прошлый раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502428) показывал. Но если Вы уже написали ту, часть, которую я давал раньше, можете ее оставить. У Вас тогда получится, что задачу решаете двумя способами: первый через интегрирование, а второй уже по формуле, которую описал выше:

```
public static Complex GetSpectralDensity(double amplitude, double angularFrequency, double duration)
{
    // Учитываем деление на 0
    if (angularFrequency == 0)
        return new Complex(amplitude * duration, 0);
    return (amplitude / (Complex.ImaginaryOne * angularFrequency)) *
        (1 - Complex.Exp(-Complex.ImaginaryOne * angularFrequency * duration));
}
```

Для вычисления спектральной плотности амплитуд нужно высчитать модуль спектральной плотности:

```
public static double GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(Complex spectralDensity)
{
    return Complex.Abs(spectralDensity);
}
```

По вашему коду и реализации:

1. Метод `GetSpectralDensity`. Зачем вы здесь считаете омегу? Омега это и есть аргумент `frequency`, его конечно, лучше переименовать в `angularFrequency`.
2. Метод `GetSinModul`. Считает непонято что, а не спектральную плотность амплитуд. Вместо выражения омега*t/2 из формулы, Вы зачем-то подставляете значение спектральной плотности, хотя эта формула и есть спектральная плотность.
3. Цикл в построении графика. Зачем здесь `counter`, который нигде не используется? Для отладки/логгирования делали?

### UPD

Метод `GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude` дает значения спектральной плотности амплитуд. Вы находите на разных угловых частотах эти значения, и строите по ним график, т.е. должно получится что-то подобное этому:

```
double amplitude = 10;
double duration = 1;
double frequencyMin = -100;
double frequenceMax = 100;
double step = 0.01;

for (double frequency = frequencyMin; frequency <= frequenceMax; frequency += step)
{
        double angularFrequency = 2 * Math.PI * frequency;
        pointList.Add(angularFrequency, GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(
            GetSpectralDensity(amplitude, angularFrequency, duration)
        ));
}

pane.AddCurve("Spectral density of the amplitude", pointList, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам !
И отвечу по поводу своего кода

1)Омегу считал отдельно в надежде что она будет влиять на график(и плюс я перечитывал разделы физики и теорию сигналов) отсюда и ошибка у меня получилась.

2)По поводу метода GetSinModul я думал что полученное значение спектральной плотности нужно подставить в модуль и считать дальше.


3)Наличие Counter в цикле был нужно для отладки и для шагов при построении графика

Comment: public static double GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(Complex spectralDensity) => Complex.Abs(spectralDensity);

Вопрос по этому методу.
Как его вызвать в других методах

каждый раз в параметрах я указываю но в Button_Click параметр не добавится,а перебивать локальную переменную нарушит вычисления.

Comment: @beginner, 2) Верно все, только вы реализовали вообще не так.
Этот метод вы вызываете когда строите график. Этот метод вернет точку

Comment: Спасибо вам.

Компилятор не даёт записать ваш метод

 public static double GetSinModul(double U, double T)
        {
            public static double GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(Complex spectralDensity);
            return Complex.Abs(spectralDensity);
        }

А если записать так

public static double GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(Complex spectralDensity) => Complex.Abs(spectralDensity);

То при вызове Button_Click он требует spectralDensity.
При объявлении spectralDensity внутри события он требует присвоения какого-либо значения

Или мне это вынести в отдельный вопрос?

Comment: @beginner, я новый синтаксис использовал. Исправлю на старый.